# Script input to a second spawned window

Tags: scripts, wine

I am attempting to write a script that spawns a Konsole window which in turn spawns a Wine CLI window, which I am able to do. I have been unsuccessful in getting the script to feed and data to the second window. For example:

```
#!/bin/bash 
echo "TEST" konsole --hold --workdir ~/.wine/drive_c/"Program Files"/DTS/MAS-SAS -e bash -c  "WINEPREFIX=~/.wine wine cmd"; echo dtshd.exe
```

The first echo appears in the first spawned Konsole window as expected.
A new Konsole window opens also as expected.
A second Wine CLI window opens as expected.

At this point the Wine window has focus, ie. any key pressed will appear in that window.

After closing the Wine window the second echo command also appears in the first Konsole window.

My question is, how, from the script, can I pass data to the second Wine window and execute it?